# Временная смена цвета

Tags: c#, wpf, task

Нужно на 2 секунды изменить цвет `Border` на другой, но по истечению времени вернуть начальный цвет(чёрный). А какой цвет будет появляться, узнаем из `bool`

```
if (true){
    Brushes.Green;
}else {
    Bruses.Red;
}
```

Примерно вот так.

Вроде бы все сделал, но куда таймер пихать не пойму. Или задержку. Как сделать?

### MathWorker.cs

```
private SolidColorBrush changeColorForSecond()
    {
        return Brushes.Green;
    }
    public async void CheckAnswer(int result, int answer)
    {
        if (result == answer)
        {
            RightAnswers++;
            SolidColorBrush resdult = await Task.Factory.StartNew(
                                         () => changeColorForSecond(),
                                         TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            WorkWindow.border.BorderBrush = resdult;
        }
        else
        {
            WrongAnswers++;
        }
    }
```

### WorkWindow.cs

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(MathAnswer.Text);
                int answer = Convert.ToInt32(new DataTable().Compute(Expression_Math.Content.ToString(), null));
                mathWorker.CheckAnswer(result, answer);
```

Comment: 1. Зачем вам смену цвета в фабрику Task'ов засовывать? 2. Где задаете элементу цвет, там и делайте что надо, скажем `WorkWindow.border.BorderBrush = resdult; await Task.Delay(1000); WorkWindow.border.BorderBrush = Bruses.Red;`.  3. Какая то у вас ооочень странная логика всего этого дела. 4. Научитесь использовать Binding и используйте MVVM, ибо смена цвета - это часть View, по сути это можно сделать триггерами.

Comment: ^+, смену цвета сделать с помощью штатной системы анимаций, а запускать по триггеру

Comment: @EvgeniyZ фабрика тасков нашёл решение как обратиться к контроль из другого процесса вот и...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно вариант номер 2 в ответ? Вроде работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если надо просто сделать задержку и повторить действие, то так и пишите:

```
WorkWindow.border.BorderBrush = resdult; //Изначальная смена цвета 
await Task.Delay(1000); //Задержка
WorkWindow.border.BorderBrush = Bruses.Red; //Вторичная смена цвета
```

Но этот подход как по мне, не очень правильный, ибо вы обращаетесь к контроллу напрямую (когда лучше использовать привязки, я уже молчу про MVVM) и по сути эту задачу можно решить простым XAML кодом (ибо смена цвета, размера шрифта или каких то еще действий с UI - это задача View).

Напишу простой пример реализации более верного подхода:

```
<Border Background="Transparent">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsAnimated}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" To="GreenYellow" Duration="0:0:0" />
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" BeginTime="0:0:5" Duration="0:0:0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

Здесь я создал некий `Border` с изначально прозрачным цветом. В стиле этого элемента я создал `DataTriger`, который привязан к некому `Bool`, если это свойство `true`, то наш триггер выполнит `DataTrigger.EnterActions`, а в нем и наша анимация.

Анимация:
По сути анимация из себя представляет временную шкалу, где каждый "тик" что то происходит. Вот мы и задаем две анимации, первая, сменит `Background` элемента на зеленый моментально (без задержек). Вторая анимация, благодаря `BeginTime` начнется с 5-ой секунды и у нее обратное действие (изменить цвет без задержки на изначальное).

Результат:

[image: Result]